# How to debug a C program producing unexpected output?

Tags: c

I am new to programming C and I don't know why my program is not printing the desired output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
  char res,res1;
 float money=10;

 printf("***Wealcome to Peace of Mind***");
 printf("\nHello we have the menu please check::");
 printf("\n***Menú***");
 printf("\n");
 printf("\n<<<Bebidas>>>");
 printf("\n 1 - Coca-Cola = 1,5     2 - IceTea = 1,4");
 printf("\n 3 - Super Bock = 1,70    4 - Sumol = 1,6");
 printf("\n");
 scanf("%d",&res);
 switch(res)
 {
    case 1 || 'Coca-Cola':money - CocaCola;break;

 }
 printf("%.1f",money);

 //Is that result i want: 
    printf("\n%.1f",10-1.5);
}
```

Output of my program:

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: `case 1 || 'Coca-Cola':money - CocaCola;break;` <-- what are you trying to do there?

Comment: Minor point of technique: please output the newline at the *end* of each line, not at the beginning.

Comment: The compiler should warn you about the wrong variable type in `scanf("%d",&res);`.

Comment: Most of this program is broken.  I recommend starting with a good introductory book on C, and work through the exercises until you have a handle on the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your `case` statement is not correct.  Also the code is using `scanf()` to read an integer, but storing the integer-sized value in a `char`.

I tidied up the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int  res;
    float cost  = 0;
    float money = 10;

    printf("***Wealcome to Peace of Mind***\n");
    printf("Hello we have the menu please check::\n");
    printf("***Menú***\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("<<<Bebidas>>>\n");
    printf(" 1 - Coca-Cola  = 1,5     2 - IceTea = 1,4\n");
    printf(" 3 - Super Bock = 1,70    4 - Sumol  = 1,6\n");
    printf("\n");

    scanf("%d", &res);

    switch(res)
    {
        case 1:
           cost = 1.5;
           break;
        case 2:
           cost = 1.4;
           break;
        // TODO: case 3 & 4
        default:
           printf("Invalid Entry\n");
           cost = 0;
    }

    printf("money = %.1f\n", money - cost);

    return 0;
}
```

Some further notes:

- As commentators pointed out, put `\n` at the end of the string
- When you compile, turn on warnings, and try to fix *all* of them.
- In `case` blocks, it's good practice to have a `default` to catch errors
- It would be worthwhile to store the drink prices as `#define` constants (or as an array of values, or some common area so the value is only set once in the program, and everything else just references that.)

  - `#define COLA_COST 1.5`

Comment: Thanks for helping me first, I'll use the tips you gave me and note down to remember. I just have difficulty using the main int (void) I've always used the void main (void) so I'll search better now on that I greet the help.

Comment: The `int main(void)` just allows the code to return an exit code.  It's the convention to return `0` for OK, and some other number to indicate an error-type.